# What do the letter suffixes mean in Intel's naming schemes?

Tags: intel-core-i5

Let's take for example the Core i5 family:

Among the processors in [this list](http://ark.intel.com/products/family/65504#@All), at the end of some CPU names there are letters like K,S,T,U,M,ME.

What do they mean?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The alphabetical suffixes are explained in detail on [this page](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/processor-numbers.html). For example:

[image: 1]

Comment: You can also see additional info on the Wikipedia pages related to the different microarchitectures such as Ivy Bridge, Sandy Bridge etc.

Comment: And what does R mean... Like i5-4570R?

Comment: @dudelgrincen: The page I linked to seems to have the explanation, in case you missed it ("Desktop processor based on BGA1364 (mobile) package with high performance graphics").